# Can a docker (community edition) overlay network be accessed from internet (with out port-forwarding)?

Tags: docker, overlay, docker-swarm

I have a docker SWARM (conected with docker overylay network) with 5 host (4 worker and 1 master). I will be deploying my application along with load balancer/gateway on this swarm. So far so good, but how can I access the gateway from the internet.
1) I don't want to use port-forwading.
2) I don't want to use Docker Enterprise Edition / Http Routing mesh.
3) I don't want to use Weave Net etc third party Net Plugins.

With these restrictions is it possible to access the gateway from net.

Answer (score 0):

If you create a Swarm Cluster With Overlay network driver, 
you will be getting a gateway for Docker which will be having a private IP Address attached to a Interface which is created by Docker Daemon.
Attach a Public IP to this Interface (as we do in AWS, we will be having a Private IP Address attached to a Interface and will be attaching a Public Ip Address).